# Could not initialize class com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.TypesafeDriverConfig

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using `Azure Databricks` solution to connect to `Cassandra`. My `Cassandra` instance is exposed at some specific port and accessible from `cqlsh`.
`Cassandra` SHOW versions returns:

`[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 3.11.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]`

I've created `Cluster` that runs on runtime:

`7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)`

I've installed following libraries:
`com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.12.0` and `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.1`

Now I'm trying to execute simple query to load data with Dataframes:

```
spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", ...)
.option("spark.cassandra.auth.username", ...)
.option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", ...)
.option("table", ...)
.option("keyspace", ...)
.load()
```

In response I'm getting:
`java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at  :: Could not initialize class com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.TypesafeDriverConfig`

How can I correctly initialize connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `spark-cassandra-connector-assembly` ([Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly)) instead of `spark-cassandra-connector`. The reason - Spark Cassandra Connector uses newer version of Typesafe Config library than Databricks runtime.  The assembly version includes all necessary libraries as shaded versions. And you don't need to install `java-driver-core` - it will be pulled as dependency automatically.

You can find more explanations in the following [blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/working-with-datastax-astra-from.html)

Comment: I was playing with that and yesterday found and answer. Thanks for response and marking this for future usage :)